# How to process forms in zappajs?

Tags: node.js, coffeescript

Currently I write in express style:

```
@use 'bodyParser'

@app.post '/add_weibo', (req, res) -> ...
```

Then get the values from `req.body`.

Zappa has an elegant way for GET method:

```
@get '/': ->
```

Is there a similar way for POST method?

Comment: Did you try `@post '/add_weibo': ->`?

Comment: I have tried `@post` but I don't know how to get values from submitted form? Since no `req` has been passed to `@post`, I cannot get them from `req.body`.

Comment: http://zappajs.github.io/zappajs/docs/reference
Inside the callback function just use `@req.body`

Comment: @Tharabas Have not found `@req.body` in the doc. Do you mean @body (shortcut to @request.body)? And I have tested `@post` with `@body` works! Thanks!

Comment: umm, yeah, zappajs is full of shortcuts. Quite handy if you know them. AFAIK `@req` is a shortcut for the `request` argument (compared to express' callbacks) so that should have worked as well. But I'm glad `@body` works for you ;)